# Change a registry value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, registry, uac

I have searched a lot to find a solution for my problem, but I can't find any specific solution.

I need to change a value which is stored under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\APP_NAME`. It is not possible to use .NET's registry functions, since they have drastic restrictions.

The following snippet should solve my problem:

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
Dim ver As Decimal
regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\APP_NAME", True)
```

regKey.SetValue("IP", "192.168.10.15:18500")
   regKey.Close()

Unfortunately, I get a NullReferenceExeption when I try to set the value.

What should I do? I have imported Microsoft.Win32 and RegistryKey doesn't accept any constructor.

Comment: Does the Sub-Key exist? And also on which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I dont think that SubKey exists 
Try this

My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\APP_NAME",True)

Comment: You need to create a subkey first of all then only you can set the value, moreover make sure that the key exists before trying to read it otherwise it will keep throwing same exception again and again

Comment: the subkey exists for shure. the exact path of the Subkey is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ABC\APP\Init"

Comment: Funnily, I am now able to read and write values with success, but I can't see the changes within regedit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" from the key name, that's already covered by the LocalMachine member in your code.

Beware that this code will not work on a regular Vista or Win7 machine, you cannot open this key for writing with UAC enabled.  You'd need a manifest that requires administrator privileges.  Write to My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser instead.

One more complication is registry virtualization if you run this on the 64-bit version of Windows.  32-bit programs will read and write HKLM\Software keys to/from HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really what I've expected, Windows 7 causes the problem.

I need to run my appliaction with administrator privileges, since the key MUST be stored under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" (it's a third party application).

Answer (score 2):

Does the subkey exists? Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d%28VS.80%29.aspx): *Rather than throwing an exception, a null reference (Nothing  in Visual Basic) is returned if the requested key does not exist.*.

Comment: The Subkey exists for shure. I have used two different ways to check this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need you need to do this:

```
regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE",True).OpenSubKey("APP_NAME", True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now able to store the key, but I can't see the change in the Windows Registry Editor.

When I use my function to read the value, I get the right value. Is there something different when using Windows 7? I had already some troubles with the VirtualStore...

Comment: @mhofer TBH I'm not sure, it works for Win XP but I haven't got a Win 7 box to test it on at the moment.