# Registry Restore programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry, restore

I want to compare all registry values to another .reg file or a .txt file and make desired changes in the system registry...
How to do this in vb.net ?

Comment: I'd sleep on this and start thinking how you could possibly compare *all* registry values to a .reg file that doesn't contain all of them.  And the kind of artificial intelligence needed to guess that a change is "desired".

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is My.Computer.Registry - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sykcb9xf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx for details.  Also, [save and load value from registry in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973377/save-and-load-value-from-registry-in-vb-net) and [Change a registry value in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043714/change-a-registry-value-in-vb-net) have some very good information.